# understanding this regex

Tags: java, regex, jmx

I m trying to understand what the following does.

```
^([^=]+)(?:(?:\\=)(.+))?$
```

Any ideas?

This is being used here. Obviously it s command line parser but i m trying to understand the syntax so i can actually run the program. This is from [commandline-jmxclient](http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/) , they have no documents on setting JMX properties but in their source code, there is such an option, so i just want to understand how i can invoke that method.

```
  Matcher m = Client.CMD_LINE_ARGS_PATTERN.matcher(command);
  if ((m == null) || (!m.matches())) {
    throw new ParseException("Failed parse of " + command, 0);
  }

  this.cmd = m.group(1);
  if ((m.group(2) != null) && (m.group(2).length() > 0))
    this.args = m.group(2).split(",");
  else
    this.args = null;
```

Comment: Both top answers are correct (Dmitry's and FailedDev's). It should be noted that this regex could be simplified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the explanation would be this :

```
"
^           # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [^=]        # Match any character that is NOT a “=”
      +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(?:         # Match the regular expression below
   (?:         # Match the regular expression below
      =           # Match the character “=” literally
   )
   (           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      .           # Match any single character that is not a line break character
         +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
)?          # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$           # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

It will capture everything before = to backreference 1 and everything after it to backrefrence 2.

e.g.

```
33333098320498
adhajdh =3232-40923-04924-0924
```

For the first string everything is capture into $1.

For the second one :

```
adhajdh  <---------- captured to $1
3232-40923-04924-0924 <----- captured to $2
```

Comment: I really don't think those annotated regex trees are worthwhile; too much detail, too much repetition, not enough big picture.

Answer (score 5):

it says "any number of characters that are not '=' optionally followed by '=' followed by any number of any character"

but you really should read up on [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: +1 for the answer and i came across regex in very rare cases really. never needed to read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets make sure we're all talking about the same regex.  It was probably created something like this:

```
public static final Pattern CMD_LINE_ARGS_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("^([^=]+)(?:(?:\\=)(.+))?$");
```

The double backslash in (`\\=`) gets converted by the Java compiler to a single backslash, so `Pattern.compile()` sees it as `\=`, an escaped equals sign.  Which, by the way, does not need to be escaped; `^([^=]+)(?:=(.+))?$` would have worked just as well.

All together, that code is looking for a command in one of these forms:

```sh
command
command=arg
command=foo,bar
command=abc,123,xyz
```

...and so on.  The first part regex - `([^=]+)` - captures the "command", that being everything before the first equals if there is one, or the whole string if not.  The second part is made optional by surrounding it with a non-capturing group controlled by a `?` quantifier.  If there is an equals sign `(?:\\=)` will consume it, and then `(.+)` will capture the rest of the string.

If the match succeeds, the command will be captured in group #1, but we don't know yet if there was an argument list.  If there was no equals sign, the second capturing group will not have participated in the match, and `m.group(2)` will return `null`.  Otherwise, we split it on commas to break out the individual arguments.

But that code only takes you so far.  It will accept these inputs too, but you'll have to test them to see if they're valid:

```sh
command= foo , bar  # surrounding spaces okay/will be trimmed?
command=foo bar     # internal spaces okay?
command=foo,        # one-item args list, no problem
command=,           # zero-item args list, could be trouble
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), it will show you what the different characters do.